Compartmentalized Contacts
Many Android apps don't work properly with Contacts access fully denied. This limits the applicability of the Android's built-in Permissions model when dealing with Contacts protection.
Hence the question:
Are there ways for fine-grained Contacts restrictions on a per-app basis in Android?
Like one of:

Present zero contacts to a given app while still allowing contacts access
Limit the list of Contacts fields available to a given app. (E.g. do not present the Notes or Address fields to a messaging app)

For rooted phones there is the excellent
XPrivacyLua, effectively providing API firewall functionality, where you e.g. present empty contacts list by default while allowing full contacts list to selected apps.
Do we have something similar for non-rooted devices?
Anything like a Contacts proxy or a virtual contacts provider?

Nothing. To do this you need to inject Android Framework (which XPrivacyLua does). This requires root//BTW even with XPrivacyLua you can't have compartmentalized granularity like show one set of contacts for app A, another for App B etc. Contacts permission is something you can't deny on a non-rooted phone. Some apps like Gpay won't work if you deny contacts =show empty list. I don't have enough technical understanding to make an answer of it but that's the reality
